# Autostarting a python script whenever it crashes

Tags: shell-script, python, raspberry-pi, mysql, autostart

I am trying to autostart a python script everytime it crashes on my raspberry pi. I am adhering to the shell script solution offered here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14735/how-do-i-restart-a-python-program-on-my-pi-when-it-crashes

In the root directory, I created a shell script with `sudo nano constantrun.sh`.

The contents of this shell script is currently  (after taking into account changes offered in the comments and answers):

```
#!/bin/sh

COMMAND='python home/pi/projects/mypythonscript.py'
LOGFILE=restart.txt

writelog() {
  now=`date`
  echo "$now $*" >> $LOGFILE
}

writelog "Starting"
while true ; do
  $COMMAND
  writelog "Exited with status $?"
  writelog "Restarting"
done
```

I then ran `sudo chmod +x constantrun.sh` to make it executable.

Following that, I ran the script with `sudo sh constantrun.sh` successfully.

The script can now initialise. However, as my python script uses a mysqlconnector module, the error I recieve now is : `Traceback (most recent call last): File "mypythonscript.py", line 8, in <module> import mysql.connector as mariadb ImportError: No module named mysql.connector`

Using a file explorer, it appears that the mysql.connnector is found installed in `home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql_connector-‌​‌​2.1.6.dist-info`

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: I use `python mypythonscript.py` on terminal

Comment: The shell acts (almost) exactly the same when run interactively as in a script. Try calling the program the same way you normally would, and see what changes

Comment: Thanks Fox. Adding the quotes made a difference. I dont have the error as previously described but now I have: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mypythonscript.py", line 8, in <module>
    import mysql.connector as mariadb
ImportError: No module named mysql.connector` 'mysql.connector' is one of the modules used in this script. 'mypythonscript.py' works otherwise when I use bash commands `python mypythonscript.py` on terminal. I was thinking whether there could be something I could add in the shell script to enable the mysql.connector to be imported into the python script?

Comment: @Fox. In terminal, if I run `python mypythonscript.py` (without sudo) at the directory where file is stored, it works without problems or the import error as described. What do you mean by checking the environment for these variables?

Comment: Where/how is the mysql module installed?

Comment: @ multithr3at3d Using a file explorer, I found the file at /home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql_connector-‌​2.1.6.dist-info

Comment: When you run with `sudo`, it acts as if you are root instead of your regular user. You could install the packages you need globally, or try setting the variable `PYTHONPATH=/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Comment: @Fox. For the latter option, does that mean adding `PYTHONPATH=/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` above `COMMAND='python home/pi/projects/mypythonscript.py'` in my shell script?

Comment: It doesn't have to be above `COMMAND=…`, but somewhere before you call `$COMMAND`, yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of running the shell script has now been resolved, thanks to the input of those who have commented/answered on my query. Chief among the helpful suggestions were Fox's suggestion to use a quotation at my command line of the shell script and the recommendation to reinstall the module required by my python script globally.

In summary, my shell script reads:

```
#!/bin/sh

COMMAND='python home/pi/projects/mypythonscript.py'
LOGFILE=restart.txt

writelog() {
  now=`date`
  echo "$now $*" >> $LOGFILE
}

writelog "Starting"
while true ; do
  $COMMAND
  writelog "Exited with status $?"
  writelog "Restarting"
done
```

I then ran `sudo chmod +x constantrun.sh` to make it executable.
Following that, I ran the script with `sudo sh constantrun.sh`

I then encountered an importmodule error: `ImportError: No module named mysql.connector`

This was resolved by doing a pip uninstall of the mysql.connector. I then proceeded with a global install of mysql.connector with `sudo pip install mysql-connector-python`. My shell script could then be launched successfully with `sudo sh constantrun.sh`.

However, though it is working currently, I am not entirely sure if this method can indeed help in the long run, of restarting the script automatically if it crashes. I will monitor further to see if this method works.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `x` permission (for execution) on your `mypythonscript.py`. You need to use `chmod` for that:

`chmod +x /home/pi/projects/mypythonscript.py`

Also, you may need a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) for your python script, for example:

`#!/usr/bin/python3`

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env python3` will work on more systems than `#!/usr/bin/python3`, since installation in `/usr/local`, `/opt`, or other paths isn't uncommon

Comment: @林自均 I have ran `chmod +x /home/pi/projects/mypythonscript.py`in terminal, as well as adding the shebang line into my python script (tried Fox's version as well). The error I still get on terminal is:`pi@raspberrypi:~/projects $ sudo sh constantrun.sh
constantrun.sh: 3: constantrun.sh: mypythonscript.py: not found`

Comment: Can you update 2 things to your main post: the content of current `constantrun.sh` and how you run your `constantrun.sh`?

Comment: @林自均 ok, updated